# Mistake in Solving Linear Recurrence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to find a closed for solution to the following:

$$a_n = -4a_{n-1}-3a_{n-2}+4a_{n-3}+4a_{n-4}$$

With $a_0=3, a_1=2, a_2 = 6, a_3 = 8$.

**My Attempt:**

I want to first find the roots:

$$r^4+4r^3+3r^2-4r-4=0$$

The roots are: $r=-1,r=1,r=-2$.

Then we can set up the following: $a_n = \alpha_1\cdot -1^n+\alpha_2\cdot1^n+ \alpha_3 \cdot-2^n$.

Now I can solve for the constants $\alpha$:

$$a_0 = 3= -\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3 \\ a_1 =2= -\alpha_1+\alpha_2-2\alpha_3 \\ a_2 =6= -\alpha_1+\alpha_2-4\alpha_3 \\ a_3=8 = -\alpha_1+\alpha_2-8\alpha_3 \\$$

But when try to solve for the constants I get that there is no solution for the system. I was wondering if someone can point out my mistakes on this recurrence problem.

Comment: The polynomial $r^4+4r^3+3r^2-4r-4$ has a double root at $-2$, so the general solution has a term of the form $n(-2)^n$.  Note that $A_n=n(-2)^n$ does satisfy the given recursion (though with different initial conditions).

Comment: Whenever two operations come back-to-back, separate them by parenthesis like $a_1\cdot (-1)$. This will mostly kill the confusion.

Comment: @lulu, so you're saying that for the expression for $(-2)^n$ it should actually be $n(-2)^n$?

Comment: @lulu Never mind! I figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two mistakes are that $-1^n$ and $-2^n$ should instead be $(-1)^n$ and $(-2)^n$.  A third mistake is that you ignored the fact that $-2$ is a double root.

---

An alternative approach is to use generating functions.  Let $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$.  Then the recurrence and initial conditions imply that
\begin{align}
A(z) 
&= \sum_{n=0}^3 a_n z^n + \sum_{n=4}^\infty a_n z^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^3 a_n z^n + \sum_{n=4}^\infty (-4a_{n-1}-3a_{n-2}+4a_{n-3}+4a_{n-4}) z^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^3 a_n z^n - 4 z \sum_{n=4}^\infty a_{n-1}z^{n-1}-3 z^2 \sum_{n=4}^\infty a_{n-2}z^{n-2} +4z^3\sum_{n=4}^\infty a_{n-3}z^{n-3}+4z^4\sum_{n=4}^\infty a_{n-4} z^{n-4} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^3 a_n z^n - 4 z (A(z)-a_0-a_1z-a_2z^2)-3 z^2 (A(z)-a_0-a_1z) +4z^3 (A(z)-a_0)+4z^4 A(z) \\
&= (-4z-3z^2+4z^3+4z^4)A(z) + a_0 + (4a_0+a_1 )z + (3a_0+4a_1+a_2 )z^2 + (-4a_0+3a_1+4a_2+a_3 )z^3 \\
&= (-4z-3z^2+4z^3+4z^4)A(z) + 3 + 14z + 23z^2 + 26z^3,
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
A(z)&=\frac{3 + 14z + 23z^2 + 26z^3}{1+4z+3z^2-4z^3-4z^4} \\
&=\frac{11/3}{1 - z} - \frac{7}{1 + z} + \frac{25/3}{1 + 2 z} - \frac{2}{(1 + 2 z)^2} \\
&=\frac{11}{3}\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n - 7\sum_{n \ge 0} (-z)^n + \frac{25}{3}\sum_{n \ge 0} (-2z)^n - 2\sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+1}{1}(-2 z)^n \\
&=\sum_{n \ge 0} \left(\frac{11}{3} - 7(-1)^n + \frac{25}{3}(-2)^n - 2(n+1)(-2)^n\right)z^n \\
&=\sum_{n \ge 0} \left(\frac{11}{3} - 7(-1)^n + \frac{19}{3}(-2)^n + n(-2)^{n+1}\right)z^n,
\end{align}
which immediately yields explicit formula
$$a_n = \frac{11}{3} - 7(-1)^n + \frac{19}{3}(-2)^n + n(-2)^{n+1}.$$

Comment: So with the extra root of $-2$, should the closed from with the constants look like: $a_n = \alpha_1\cdot (-1)^n+\alpha_2\cdot1^n+ \alpha_3 \cdot n(-2)^n$?

Comment: Yes, and one more term: $+\alpha_4\cdot (-2)^n$